# Allowing Wildcards in Access Query

Tags: ms-access, vba

I was wondering if someone could help me with this. I have a form in Access that has a combo box to look up an item number. Right now the Row Source is something like

```
  Select ItemCode, ItemDescription From MyTable Where ItemType = 'G'
```

I would like to change it to allow a wild card.  So right now if you type in C* it will not work. How do I make that work?  Do I just update it to say

```
Select ItemCode From MyTable Where ItemType = 'G'
```

or is there more to it?

It's calling a query which is calling a SQL database.  It's passing parameters like the date and itemcode.

It's calling a pass-through query to the database That looks like this...

pt_JobAnalysis '12/26/2017' , '01/26/2018' , '' , '10516' , ''

sSQL = sProcedureName & " '" & Me.txtFrom & "' , '" & Me.txtTo & "'"

Thank you so much.

Comment: `= 'C*'` looks for the exact string `"C*"` instead use `LIKE 'C*'` which looks for anything beginning with `C`.

Comment: Thank you. Typed in  LIKE 'C*'  and got ODBC Call falied.  Incorrect syntax near 'C'   LIKE C* returns nothing.  Thanks

Comment: If you did it right it should have worked: `Select ItemCode, ItemDescription From MyTable Where ItemType LIKE 'C*'`. The only other thing (and it is very unlikely) is that the way you connect your tables from SQL server means you have to use SQL server wildcard `%` instead of MS Access wildcard `*`

Comment: I see, thank you. I was trying to type it in the combo box. Is there any way to do that?  They don't want to change the way the report works now. It still needs to be able to look it up on an item by item basis.  It is in SQL Server.

Comment: Why are you filtering the RowSource? Let the combobox AutoExpand property work for you. Do you want to allow input of values not in the list?

Comment: Why are you filtering the RowSource?  - I didn't create this app.  Do you want to allow input of values not in the list? - It's just pulling a report, so I don't see why not?  Let the combobox AutoExpand property work for you. - I'll have to look into that. I don't work much in Access so I'm not sure what you mean. Thanks.

Comment: I believe the comments above are confusing the RowSource with the value of the combo-box and how it is being used. The RowSource just populates the combo-box list. What you type into the combo-box is used elsewhere (you said it filters a report). What is the ControlSource of the combo-box? How is the report referencing this combo-box value? E.g. is a report using a filter like `Field1 = Forms!Form1!Combo1`? Typing `Like 'C*'` can't work in that case. But you can change it to `Field1 LIKE Forms!Form1!Combo1` and it will now accept criteria such as `C*`.

Comment: It would be best to update the actual question with complete and correct details.  It is confusing to provide the details only in the comments, and Stack Overflow is best when the questions are updated so they can help others without trudging through the comments.  The question says " It's passing parameters", but there is no indication of parameters in the SQL statements.  What parameters?

Comment: Thank you. I updated the original question. I'm sorry I thought someone told me not to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should do it:

```
"Like '*'"
```

OR . . .

```
If IsNull(Me.txtFirstName.Value) Then
    strFirstName = "Like '*'"
Else
    SelectCase Me.fraFirstName.Value
        Case 1
            strFirstName = "Like '" & Me.txtFirstName.Value & "*'"
        Case 2
            strFirstName = "Like '*" & Me.txtFirstName.Value & "*'"
        Case 3
            strFirstName = "Like '*" & Me.txtFirstName.Value & "'"
        Case 4
            strFirstName = "= '" & Me.txtFirstName.Value & "'"
    End Select
End If
```

FINALLY . . . 
The link below should help you a lot!

https://www.fontstuff.com/access/acctut19.htm